# about change the location of TFS 2017 Databases

Tags: tfs

i attempt to backup and restore tfs database to a auther server

Any idea about risk ?

and How i can manage TFS Server to change the new  location of TFS database ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could move Azure DevOps Server/TFS from one machine to another by restoring it to new hardware (called a restoration-based move).

When you move to a new server you do not lose any of your project history.

> One risk
>
> In some situations you might want to change the domain of a Azure
>   DevOps Server deployment as well as its hardware. Changing the domain
>   is an environment-based move, and you should **never combine the two
>   move types**. First complete the hardware move, and then change the
>   environment.

Besides, another place need to pay attention to. You must **have a complete set of data backups for the SQL Server databases**. If the data was encrypted, you must also have the encryption key and its password.
For more information, see [Back up Azure DevOps Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/admin/backup/manually-backup-tfs?view=azure-devops)

You must back up the TFS_Warehouse and TFS_Analysis databases if your deployment is configured to use SQL Server Reporting Services and you want to restore those databases to a different server. You cannot just rebuild the warehouse, as you can when you restore to the same server or instance.

Once the backup completes, verify that the backup is available on the storage device or network share, and that you can access this backup from the new hardware.

Actually, we do have a detail step-by-step official tutorial, you could kindly refer and follow it-- [Move or clone from one hardware to another for Azure DevOps on-premises](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/admin/move-clone-hardware?view=azure-devops)

Comment: i would only change the location of vsts database from one vm to author

Comment: HI @KivenWanda Thanks for quickly getting back. Sorry not totally get your point of your comment. `i would only change the location of vsts database from one vm to author` You used TFS2017 in your question title. But for this comment you  point out it's vsts, vsts database handle in could by MSFT, we could not change them. Besides what do you mean of author server? Could you explain more clearly, better to provide a link a screenshot.

Comment: i would change the same vsts database from server X to server Y

Comment: Yes @KivenWanda  Guess you mean TFS on-premise database, since we do not be able to change vsts database. If you would like to do this, change the same database from server X to server Y, it's just **move from one hardware to another** . You should simply follow the tutorial  mentioned in the answer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/admin/move-clone-hardware?view=azure-devops It contain step-by-step process and any risk / attention.